# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on code that solves quadratic formula

Tags: python, math, int

So I wanted to create some code to make my math homework slightly quicker. I have created code that inputs a,b and c which are then placed into the mathematicla formula. This is my first math code so there might be some obvious issues. Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
import math
num1 = int(input("Enter a:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter b:"))
num3 = int(input("Enter c:"))
result1 = (-num2 + math.sqrt(num2^2 - 4 * (num1)(num3)))
result2 = (result1 / (2 * num1))
print(result2)
```

Comment: try using the operator * between parentheses.

Comment: [`num2^2`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_operators.htm) does probably not do, what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the operator "*" between num1 and num3 parentheses did the trick:

```
import math
num1 = int(input("Enter a:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter b:"))
num3 = int(input("Enter c:"))
result1 = (-num2 + math.sqrt(num2**2 - 4 * (num1)*(num3)))
result2 = (result1 / (2 * num1))
print(result2)
```

**Edit**

If you want to allow complex results, use cmath's sqrt function.

```
import cmath
num1 = int(input("Enter a:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter b:"))
num3 = int(input("Enter c:"))
result1 = (-num2 + cmath.sqrt(num2**2 - 4 * (num1)*(num3)))
result2 = (result1 / (2 * num1))
print(result2)
```

Comment: @DiegoContreras you cant use the `^` operator for power. that is the XOR operator. you need to change it to `num2**2`

Comment: You're also missing the `num3` input

Comment: the num3 was a mistake when I copy pasted it. Try refreshing the page, I edited it

Comment: so adding the ** hasn't changed anything. Now I'm getting ValueError: math domain error

Comment: @T.ps: if you input bad numbers (such that the arg to the square root is less than zero) then you correctly get that error

Comment: @T.ps, you should input correct values! try with num1=3, num2=10, num3=2

Comment: @RishiG That's it! I was reviewing it with a=1 b=2 c=3 but tried it with other random numbers which then worked. Is there any way to allow the number 1 to be used?

Comment: @T.ps what do you mean with "be used"?

Comment: I would like to have the ability to use the number "1" without it giving me an error.

Comment: @T.ps The reason " ValueError: math domain error " is being displayed is because the square root of a negative number is a complex number, that's why! in order to don't get this error be sure on whatever input you make the number inside the square root is always greater than zero.

Comment: Problem is that most math equations involve a negative :/ Is there no way to allow it?

Comment: @T.ps then i highly encourage you to use cmath library which has a built-it function sqrt() that allows complex results. i will update my edit with an example.

Answer (score 0):

So python code has different operators than some languages like mathematica. Try this instead.

```
import math
num1 = int(input("Enter a:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter b:"))
num3 = int(input("Enter c:"))
result1 = (-num2 + math.sqrt(num2**2 - 4 * (num1)*(num3)))
result2 = (result1 / (2 * num1))
print(result2)
```

the power operator is `**` instead of `^` (that is the XOR operator). and multiplication needs to be explicitly stated using the `*` operator even if its between parentheses.

Comment: @T.ps it seems to work when i input examples. What inputs do you have?

Comment: Yep, I found out that the number 1 doesn't work. Any way to allow the number 1 into the equation?

Comment: @T.ps, sure. You can use (1, -1, -2) i.e. x^2 -x -2 and it should output 2.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a quadratic equation solver. While it looks like there is already an accepted answer to this question, I would like to add some additional code of my own to address some possible pitfalls.

It looks like you are getting a `ValueError: math domain error` issues since you are passing "invalid" values to your `a, b, c` variables. This is due to the fact that python does not handle taking the square root of negative numbers with `math.sqrt`. **However**, if you want to get the imaginary solutions as well, I would recommend you use python's built-in support for handling complex numbers and use the `cmath.sqrt` as well. I suggest that you calculate and store the `discriminant` (i.e. the stuff under square root sign) as a separate variable. Your solver code might look like this (note that I also solve for **both** solutions as there is a ± symbol in the quadratic formula to consider):

```
import math
import cmath#complex number math module!!!

def solve_quadratic_equation(a, b, c):
    disc = b**2 - (4*a*c)#disc = discriminant
    sqrt_disc = cmath.sqrt(disc) if disc < 0 else math.sqrt(disc)#ternary if
    pos_answer = (-b + sqrt_disc)/(2*a)
    neg_answer = (-b - sqrt_disc)/(2*a)
    return (pos_answer, neg_answer)

def get_input():
    a = int(input("Enter a: "))
    b = int(input("Enter b: "))
    c = int(input("Enter c: "))
    return (a, b, c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b, c = get_input()
    answer = solve_quadratic_equation(a, b, c)
    print(answer)
```